# Android tests fail unless test dependencies are included in application

Tags: android, gradle, automated-tests

We have Android tests that run in the emulator (or on a real device).

Recently, these tests started failing to run, with the following errors:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getDeclaringClass()Ljava/lang/Class; in class Lorg/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod' appears in /data/app/com.example.myapp-AYAInqNVkGzlPMGy6LaKSw==/base.apk!classes19.dex)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.UiThreadStatement.classHasAnnotation(UiThreadStatement.java:98)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.UiThreadStatement.hasAnnotation(UiThreadStatement.java:93)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.UiThreadStatement.shouldRunOnUiThread(UiThreadStatement.java:74)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.methodInvoker(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:162)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:444)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
```

and

```
01-27 11:35:48.687 10255 10303 E TestRunner: failed: loginTest(com.example.myapp.activities.uitests.LoginTest)
01-27 11:35:48.688 10255 10303 E TestRunner: ----- begin exception -----
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/hamcrest/Matchers;
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId(ViewMatchers.java:1)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at com.example.myapp.activities.TestingPermissions.loginMethod(TestingPermisions.kt:75)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at com.example.myapp.activities.uitests.LoginTest.loginTest(LoginTest.kt:37)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:549)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:134)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:162)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:444)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.hamcrest.Matchers" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapp.test-O96KLGwojXcLFHg_hVK1-A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapp-rGS0dWVmuKcmSSbiwfPtPA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapp.test-O96KLGwojXcLFHg_hVK1-A==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myapp-rGS0dWVmuKcmSSbiwfPtPA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myapp.test-O96KLGwojXcLFHg_hVK1-A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myapp-rGS0dWVmuKcmSSbiwfPtPA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner:    ... 34 more
01-27 11:35:48.698 10255 10303 E TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
```

Going back through the git history, I found that these errors began when these lines in `build.gradle` were changed:

#### Before

```
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
```

#### After

```
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
```

The last two testing dependencies were formerly set as `implementation` dependencies, and one of our developers saw that and said "hey, that's not correct, since those are only for testing". The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/test-setup) clearly says that `androidTestImplementation` is the correct thing to use here.

Why are my tests be failing if these dependencies are set up properly? How can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you run but this dependencies will only be included for instrumented tests. Are you running instrumented tests or plain java unit tests? If it's the later use 'testImplementation'.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann these are instrumented tests